# How to add a ArcGISMapServer to QGIS in QGIS 3.20.2

Tags: gis, arcgis, qgis, esri, arcmap

I am trying to add a ArcGISMapServer connection to my QGIS workspace in QGIS 3.20.2. The option for adding a this connection does not appear in the data source manager or in the add layers option. There is now only an option for adding an ArcGIS Rest Server:

[QGIS 3.20.2 View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjLP3.png)

In previous versions there was an in built option for adding these connections:

[Previous QGIS versions option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoSwS.jpg)

Is there a new method of adding in ArcGIS Map Server connections in more recent versions of QGIS?

Answer (score 0):

In the Browser, you can find the "ArcGIS REST Servers" Option.  Right click to add a server.  Then you can

[image]

Then you can add a server name and the URL to access the layers.  Provide authentication, if needed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS Map Server and ArcGIS Rest Server are the same thing. You can add your ArcGIS Server maps from new ArcGIS Rest Server section.